# @Html.DropDownList() No muestra el valor selecionado del ViewData["algunacosa"]

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Tengo un SelectListItem y en un elemento pongo Selected = true, pero al pasar este objeto a razor en un @Html.DropDownList() este no reconoce el elemento selecionado.

[image: Como se muestra en la imagen quiero que aparesca el segundo elemento como seleccionado ya que este es el que tiene selected = true]

De esta forma es como lo tengo en mi vista Razor

```
@Html.DropDownList("ListaProgramas", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["ListaProgramas"], new {@class = "form-control pull-left", @id = "ListaProgramas", @style = "color:black; width:100%;" })

List<SelectListItem> listItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
                        {
                            Text = row["ProgramName"].ToString().Trim(),
                            Value = row["Id"].ToString().Trim(),
                            Selected = valor

                        });
```

pongo un solo elemento de esta lista como selected, ese es el que pretendo que aparesca como selecionado en razor view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ver si me explico mejor de esta forma. En la variable Empleados tengo almacenado una lista de empleados, los cuales tienen: "Id", "Nombre" y "Apellidos". Esa lista quiero renderizarla en una vista mediante el helper @HtmlDropDownList pero quiero que me salga seleccionado por defecto x empleado. Esto es lo que necesita Elvin Acevedo.

en mi controlador:

```
 ViewBag.EmpleadoId = new SelectList(Empleados, "Id", "Nombre", 1);
```

yo uso ViewBag pero eso no viene al caso pues es lo mismmo que ViewData. Sería buena esa pregunta. "Diferencias entre ViewBag y ViewData". volviendo al tema, el primer valor pasado como parámetro en mi ViewBag es Empleados, el cual es la lista de empleados que quiero mostrar, el segundo valor representa el valor que voy a recoger al seleccionar, en este caso quiero recoger como "select value" el Id del empleado seleccionado, el tercer parámetro es el campo que voy a mostrar en mi select list, como ven tengo "Nombre", por lo que en mi select list al desplegarla veré los nombres de todos los empleados, y ahora es donde viene el cuarto parámetro que es opcional pero que representa el "select value" que tanto quiere mi amigo Elvis por defecto, como yo estoy recogiendo el "Id" ya que lo he definido en el segundo parámetro entonces en el cuarto parámetro debería poner el valor de un Id, tal y como lo he definido arriba en el ejemplo de mi ViewBag. Ahora vamos a llamar esto en al vista

```
@Html.DropDownList("EmpleadoId",null, String.Empty, new {aki lo de siempre para html options como class y id})
```

esto me mostrará un select list con los nombres de todos los empleados y seleccionado por defecto el empleado cuyo Id es 1. Saludos

Comment: Excelente hermano, gracias por tomarte el tiempo para responder me Vicente Almea, Saludos desde República Dominicana.

Comment: ¿por qué 2 respuestas? Si querías aclarar, deberías editar tu respuesta, no generar una nueva. Esto no es un foro

Comment: Disculpa, no me di cuenta, cosas de novatos.

Answer (score 2):

Tu DropDownList se debe de llamar diferente que el objeto que estas colocando en el ViewData (o ViewBag).

```
@Html.DropDownList("ListaProgramasHtmlSelect", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["ListaProgramas"], new { @class = "form-control pull-left", @id = "ListaProgramas", @style = "color:black; width:100%;" })
```

ó

```
@Html.DropDownList("ListaProgramas", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["ListaProgramasViewData"], new { @class = "form-control pull-left", @id = "ListaProgramas", @style = "color:black; width:100%;" })
```